# Cast dynamic to type through external static extension call stays dynamic

Tags: c#, dynamic, casting, extension-methods

I have a strange behaviour.

I use the following method to cast any object to any given type.

```
using System.Dynamic;
```

...

```
/// <summary>
/// Casts any object to passed type.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Wished type</typeparam>
/// <param name="obj">The object you want to be casted.</param>
public static T ToType<T>(this object obj) => (T)obj;
```

For example (object to dynamic):

```
AnyLabel.Tag = new ExpandoObject();
AnyLabel.Tag.ToType<dynamic>().Item2 = new Form(); // works
```

Now following situation (dynamic to typed object):

```
// var is NOT from type form, why?:
var form = ToType<Form>(AnyLabel.Tag.ToType<dynamic>().Item2);

// the other way works like desired:
var form2 = ((Form)AnyLabel.Tag.ToType<dynamic>().Item2);
```

I can not access any form properties/methods using the casting extension à la:

```
ToType<Form>(AnyLabel.Tag.ToType<dynamic>().Item2).Show();
```

My question is, why is the first var not from type form and denies me the last code part to execute?

Comment: Your code was not compilable. Please post compilable code.

Comment: Pardon. Edited.

Comment: Why do you define an extension method when you do not use it as an extension method?

Comment: this was for illustrating the problem. My desirable result is the last code part that is not possible as described above. And you cannot apply static extensions to dynamic types.

Comment: That's because compiler will not infer any types when any `dynamic` is involved. So result of `someDynamic.ToType<int>()` will not be inferred to have type int. There might not be any `ToType` method at all (for example you can do `ToTypeeee<int>` and it will still compile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `ToType<T>()` could have overloaded versions. If no dynamics are involved, the compiler resolves the right overload at compile time. If; however, dynamics are involved, the binding happens at runtime, i.e., the right overload is determined at runtime using the runtime type of the arguments. Also, these overloads could have different return types. Since now, this return type is not known at compile time, the C# compiler decides to choose `dynamic` as return type of your function.

Now, you could reason, that you don't have an overloaded version and that `Form` could safely be assumed. But what happens, if you add overloads later? Should this suddenly change the return type of an expression that did not change? Adding an overload, would introduce a breaking change to existing code that cannot be detected at compile time.

---

Which return type to choose at compile time, if overload is determined by runtime argument type?

```
public static T ToType<T>(this object obj) => (T)obj;
public static int ToType<T>(this int i) => i; // Makes no sense, but valid code.
public static dynamic ToType<T>(this dynamic d) => d; // Valid as well.
```

Comment: After reading 10 times, I understood it. So my fallacy was to think only about the expected result. Thanks!

Comment: Overload resolution can bake your noodle.

Comment: You could on base of your great answer add the solution: `ToType<Form>((object)AnyLabel.Tag.ToType<dynamic>().Item2).Show();` This indicates to which overload I want to refer. This would round up your answer and helps everyone who find this.

Comment: Yes, it is a valid use case; however, it would not help to clarify my explanation. (My answer is not about using dynamics in general but about overlaod resolution involving dynamics.) A solution would be to type the variable explicitly: `Form form = ToType<Form>(AnyLabel.Tag.ToType<dynamic>().Item2);`